# Access index in pandas.Series.apply

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a MultiIndex Series `s`:

```
>>> s
     values
a b
1 2  0.1 
3 6  0.3
4 4  0.7
```

and I want to apply a function which uses the index of the row:

```
def f(x):
   # conditions or computations using the indexes
   if x.index[0] and ...: 
   other = sum(x.index) + ...
   return something
```

How can I do `s.apply(f)` for such a function? What is the recommended way to make this kind of operations? I expect to obtain a new Series with the values resulting from this function applied on each row and the same MultiIndex.

Comment: See this discussion, seems like x.name is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658240/getting-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-pandas-apply-function

Comment: @PabloJadzinsky That discussion is about DataFrame not for Series I think

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't believe `apply` has access to the index; it treats each row as a numpy object, not a Series, as you can see:

```
In [27]: s.apply(lambda x: type(x))
Out[27]: 
a  b
1  2    <type 'numpy.float64'>
3  6    <type 'numpy.float64'>
4  4    <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

To get around this limitation, promote the indexes to columns, apply your function, and recreate a Series with the original index.

```
Series(s.reset_index().apply(f, axis=1).values, index=s.index)
```

Other approaches might use `s.get_level_values`, which often gets a little ugly in my opinion, or `s.iterrows()`, which is likely to be slower -- perhaps depending on exactly what `f` does.

Comment: Also worth noting that vectorising f, and using & | etc., may also be faster.

Comment: Currently I use the reset_index approach, will hold a little to see if someone proposes a cleaner solution.

Comment: +1 For getting rid of the `MultiIndex`. While these are occasionally useful, more and more I find myself turning my indices into columns.

Comment: In my case (a dataframe, with axis=1), x.name() returns the value of the index when I apply a function lambda x: x ...

Comment: Which is totally moronic behaviour but ye, what you say is completely right, however your solution is not ideal, for most use cases Jeff's answer `DataFrame(s).apply(x)` is much more straightforward and should be the accepted answer IMHO!

Comment: This makes sense to me, because I want the object, not the index. But when I'm creating a function x(i) and then I'm printing i, it's printing out the index. Which I unstand from everything I'm reading it shouldn't be accessing the index at all.

Answer (score 19):

Make it a frame, return scalars if you want (so the result is a series)

Setup

```
In [11]: s = Series([1,2,3],dtype='float64',index=['a','b','c'])

In [12]: s
Out[12]: 
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: float64
```

Printing function

```
In [13]: def f(x):
    print type(x), x
    return x
   ....: 

In [14]: pd.DataFrame(s).apply(f)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: float64
Out[14]: 
   0
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

Since you can return anything here, just return the scalars (access the index via the `name` attribute)

```
In [15]: pd.DataFrame(s).apply(lambda x: 5 if x.name == 'a' else x[0] ,1)
Out[15]: 
a    5
b    2
c    3
dtype: float64
```

Comment: so when calling `apply` on `DataFrame` its index will be accessible through `name` of each series? I see this also is true for `DateTimeIndex` but it is a little weird to use something similar to `x.name == Time(2015-06-27 20:08:32.097333+00:00)`

Comment: This should be the answer, adopting `x.name` is the cleanest and most flexible way of addressing the problem.

Answer (score 14):

Convert to `DataFrame` and apply along row. You can access the index as `x.name`. `x` is also a `Series` now with 1 value

```
s.to_frame(0).apply(f, axis=1)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You *may* find it faster to use `where` rather than `apply` here:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a' ,'b', 'c'])

In [12]: s.where(s.index != 'a', 5)
Out[12]: 
a    5
b    2
c    3
dtype: float64
```

Also you can use numpy-style logic/functions to any of the parts:

```
In [13]: (2 * s + 1).where((s.index == 'b') | (s.index == 'c'), -s)
Out[13]: 
a   -1
b    5
c    7
dtype: float64

In [14]: (2 * s + 1).where(s.index != 'a', -s)
Out[14]: 
a   -1
b    5
c    7
dtype: float64
```

*I recommend testing for speed (as efficiency against apply will depend on the function). Although, I find that `apply`s are more readable...*

Comment: Hm. Now I wonder if there should be a `Series.eval`/`query` method...I'll bring this up over at pandas.

Comment: @PhillipCloud, +1, I need to use indices a lot(add/subs, aligns and missing data) and this would be great to have.

Comment: I'm finding increasingly more often that if I convert my `MultiIndex`es to columns I'm much happier and life is easier. There's *so* much more you can do with columns in a `DataFrame` than a `Series` with a `MultiIndex`, in fact they are essentially the same thing, except queries will be faster in the `DataFrame` columns than in the `Series`-with-`MultiIndex`.

Comment: @PhillipCloud I'm the same, they should really be first class citizens (rather than the opposite).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "Access index in pandas.Series.apply"

Answer (score 0):

You can access the whole row as argument inside the fucntion if you use DataFrame.apply() instead of Series.apply().

```
def f1(row):
    if row['I'] < 0.5:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def f2(row):
    if row['N1']==1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,1), columns=list('I'))
df4['N1']=df4.apply(f1, axis=1)
df4['N2']=df4.apply(f2, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reset_index()` to convert the Series to a DataFrame and the index to a column, and then `apply` your function to the DataFrame.

The tricky part is knowing how `reset_index()` names the columns, so here are a couple of examples.

### With a Singly Indexed Series

```
s=pd.Series({'idx1': 'val1', 'idx2': 'val2'})

def use_index_and_value(row):
    return 'I made this with index {} and value {}'.format(row['index'], row[0])

s2 = s.reset_index().apply(use_index_and_value, axis=1)

# The new Series has an auto-index;
# You'll want to replace that with the index from the original Series
s2.index = s.index
s2
```

Output:

```
idx1    I made this with index idx1 and value val1
idx2    I made this with index idx2 and value val2
dtype: object
```

### With a Multi-Indexed Series

Same concept here, but you'll need to access the index values as `row['level_*']` because that's where they're placed by `Series.reset_index()`.

```
s=pd.Series({
    ('idx(0,0)', 'idx(0,1)'): 'val1',
    ('idx(1,0)', 'idx(1,1)'): 'val2'
})

def use_index_and_value(row):
    return 'made with index: {},{} & value: {}'.format(
        row['level_0'],
        row['level_1'],
        row[0]
    )

s2 = s.reset_index().apply(use_index_and_value, axis=1)

# Replace auto index with the index from the original Series
s2.index = s.index
s2
```

Output:

```
idx(0,0)  idx(0,1)    made with index: idx(0,0),idx(0,1) & value: val1
idx(1,0)  idx(1,1)    made with index: idx(1,0),idx(1,1) & value: val2
dtype: object
```

If your series or indexes have names, you will need to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`Series` implements the `items()` method, which enables the use of list comprehensions to map keys (i.e. index values) and values.

Given a series:

```
In[1]: seriesA = pd.Series([4, 2, 3, 7, 9], name="A")
In[2]: seriesA
Out[2]:
0    4
1    2
2    3
3    7
4    9
dtype: int64
```

Now, assume function `f` that takes a key and a value:

```
def f(key, value):
    return key + value
```

We can now create a new series by using a for comprehension:

```
In[1]: pd.Series(data=[f(k,v) for k, v in seriesA.items()], index=seriesA.index)
Out[1]:
0     4
1     3
2     5
3    10
4    13
dtype: int64
```

Of course this doesn't take advantage of any numpy performance goodness, but for some of operations it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty solution is by using regex.

first, reset the index to create a dataframe.

```
df = s.reset_index()

df
a   b   values
0   1   2   0.1
1   3   6   0.3
2   4   4   0.7
```

Then create a column with concatenated columns and indexes as follows:
just make sure to use a separator that can be easily separated during pattern recognition. In my case, I use 'first_wall' and 'second_wall'

```
concatenated_series = df['a'].astype(str)+'first_wall'+df['b'].astype(str)+'second_wall'+df['values'].astype(str)

concatenated_series

0    1first_wall2second_wall0.1
1    3first_wall6second_wall0.3
2    4first_wall4second_wall0.7
dtype: object
```

Then Create the function

```
def f(x):
   first_index = int(re.search('^(.+)first_wall', x).group(1))
   second_index = int(re.search('first_wall(.+)second_wall', x).group(1))
   value = float(re.search(r'second_wall(.+)$',x).group(1))
   #do something and whatever you like
   return first_index + second_index + value
```

Then apply it to the concatenated series.

```
concatenated_series.apply(f)

0    3.1
1    9.3
2    8.7
dtype: float64
```

Cheers!