# getting the index of a row in a pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access the index of a row in a function applied across an entire `DataFrame` in Pandas. I have something like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

and I'll define a function that access elements with a given row

```
def rowFunc(row):
    return row['a'] + row['b'] * row['c']
```

I can apply it like so:

```
df['d'] = df.apply(rowFunc, axis=1)
>>> df
   a  b  c   d
0  1  2  3   7
1  4  5  6  34
```

Awesome! Now what if I want to incorporate the index into my function?
The index of any given row in this `DataFrame` before adding `d` would be `Index([u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd'], dtype='object')`, but I want the 0 and 1. So I can't just access `row.index`.

I know I could create a temporary column in the table where I store the index, but I'm wondering if it is stored in the row object somewhere.

Comment: Aside: is there a reason you need to use `apply`?  It's much slower than performing vectorized ops on the frame itself.  (Sometimes apply *is* the simplest way to do something, and performance considerations are often exaggerated, but for your particular example it's as easy *not* to use it.)

Comment: @DSM in actuality I am calling another objects constructor for each row using different row elements. I just wanted to put a minimal example together to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

To access the index in this case you access the `name` attribute:

```
In [182]:

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])
def rowFunc(row):
    return row['a'] + row['b'] * row['c']

def rowIndex(row):
    return row.name
df['d'] = df.apply(rowFunc, axis=1)
df['rowIndex'] = df.apply(rowIndex, axis=1)
df
Out[182]:
   a  b  c   d  rowIndex
0  1  2  3   7         0
1  4  5  6  34         1
```

Note that if this is really what you are trying to do that the following works and is much faster:

```
In [198]:

df['d'] = df['a'] + df['b'] * df['c']
df
Out[198]:
   a  b  c   d
0  1  2  3   7
1  4  5  6  34

In [199]:

%timeit df['a'] + df['b'] * df['c']
%timeit df.apply(rowIndex, axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 163 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 286 µs per loop
```

**EDIT**

Looking at this question 3+ years later, you could just do:

```
In[15]:
df['d'],df['rowIndex'] = df['a'] + df['b'] * df['c'], df.index
df

Out[15]: 
   a  b  c   d  rowIndex
0  1  2  3   7         0
1  4  5  6  34         1
```

but assuming it isn't as trivial as this, whatever your `rowFunc` is really doing, you should look to use the vectorised functions, and then use them against the df index:

```
In[16]:
df['newCol'] = df['a'] + df['b'] + df['c'] + df.index
df

Out[16]: 
   a  b  c   d  rowIndex  newCol
0  1  2  3   7         0       6
1  4  5  6  34         1      16
```

Comment: Would be nice if `name` would be a named tuple in case of a `Multindex`, so that a specific index level could be queried by its name.

Answer (score 64):

Either:

#### 1. with `row.name` inside the `apply(..., axis=1)` call:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'], index=['x','y'])

   a  b  c
x  1  2  3
y  4  5  6

df.apply(lambda row: row.name, axis=1)

x    x
y    y
```

#### 2. with `iterrows()` (slower)

[DataFrame.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) allows you to iterate over rows, and access their index:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    ...
```

Comment: and, if concerned, 'itertuples' generally performs far better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues

Answer (score 14):

To answer the original question: yes, you can access the index value of a row in `apply()`. It is available under the key `name` and requires that you specify `axis=1` (because the lambda processes the columns of a row and not the rows of a column).

Working example (pandas 0.23.4):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
>>> df
   b  c
a      
1  2  3
4  5  6
>>> df['index_x10'] = df.apply(lambda row: 10*row.name, axis=1)
>>> df
   b  c  index_x10
a                 
1  2  3         10
4  5  6         40
```

Comment: Also works for dataframes with MultiIndex: row.name becomes a tuple.