# Row by row processing of a Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I need to process a large file and to change some values.

I would like to do something like that:

```
for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():

        foo = doSomeStuffWith(row)
        lol = doOtherStuffWith(row)

        dataFrame['colx'][index] = foo
        dataFrame['coly'][index] = lol
```

Bad for me, I cannot do  *dataFrame['colx'][index] = foo*!

My number of row is quite large and I need to process a large number of column. So I'm afraid that dask may read the file several times if I do one dataFrame.apply(...) for each column.

Other solutions are to manually break my data into chunks and to use pandas or to just throw anything in a database. But it could be nice if I may keep using my .csv and let dask do the chunk processing for me!

Thank for your help.

Comment: Did you check out map_partitions?

Comment: How big is the file? What format is the file? The main thing to do probably is to really understand when the file would be read to avoid re-reading it unnecessarily.

Comment: @ArcoBast One reason to use this (`.iterrows`) and not `.apply` is for when there's useful data in the index, and at least according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658240/getting-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-pandas-apply-function, it's hard to access the index directly from an `.apply`

Answer (score 4):

In general iterating over a dataframe, either Pandas or Dask, is likely to be quite slow.  Additionally Dask won't support row-wise element insertion.  This kind of workload is difficult to scale.

Instead I recommend using dd.Series.where (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49639741/616616)) or else doing your iteration in a function (after making a copy so as not to operate in place) and then using map_partitions to call that function across all of the Pandas dataframes in your Dask dataframe .

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the same syntax as pandas, although it does evaluate the dask-dataframe as you go along.

```
for i in dask_df.iterrows():
     print i
```

Comment: it will load entire dataframe in memory. It doesn't work for large datasets