# Assign conditional values to columns in Dask

Tags: dataframe, dask

I am trying to do a conditional assignation to the rows of a specific column: `target`. I have done some research, and it seemed that the answer was given here: ["How to do row processing and item assignment in dask"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639579/how-to-do-row-processing-and-item-assignment-in-dask).

I will reproduce my necessity. Mock data set:

```
x = [3, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 9]
y = [200, 300, 400, 215, 219, 360, 280, 396, 145, 276, 190, 554, 355]
mock = pd.DataFrame(dict(target = x, speed = y))
```

The look of `mock` is:

```
In [4]: mock.head(7)
Out [4]:
      speed target
    0   200 3
    1   300 0
    2   400 3
    3   215 4
    4   219 0
    5   360 0
    6   280 0
```

Having this `Pandas DataFrame`, I convert it into a `Dask DataFrame`:

```
mock_dask = dd.from_pandas(mock, npartitions = 2)
```

I apply my conditional rule: all values in `target` above 0, must be 1, all others 0 (binaryze `target`). Following the mentioned thread above, it should be:

```
result = mock_dask.target.where(mock_dask.target > 0, 1)
```

I have a look at the result dataset and it is not working as expected:

```
In [7]: result.head(7)
Out [7]:
0    3
1    1
2    3
3    4
4    1
5    1
6    1
Name: target, dtype: object
```

As we can see, the column `target` in `mock` and `result` are not the expected results. It seems that my code is converting all 0 original values to 1, instead of the values that are greater than 0 into 1 (the conditional rule).

Dask newbie here, Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the documentation in [Dask DataFrame API](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=assign) is pretty clear. Thanks to @MRocklin feedback I have realized my mistake. In the documentation, `where` function (the last one in the list) is used with the following syntax:

```
DataFrame.where(cond[, other])      Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other.
```

Thus, the correct code line would be:

```
result = mock_dask.target.where(mock_dask.target <= 0, 1)
```

This will output:

```
In [7]: result.head(7)
Out [7]:
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    0
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

Which is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to be the same to me

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: x = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 9]
   ...: y = [200, 300, 400, 215, 219, 360, 280, 396, 145, 276, 190, 554, 355]
   ...: mock = pd.DataFrame(dict(target = x, speed = y))
   ...: 

In [3]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [4]: mock_dask = dd.from_pandas(mock, npartitions = 2)

In [5]: mock.target.where(mock.target > 0, 1).head(5)
Out[5]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
Name: target, dtype: int64

In [6]: mock_dask.target.where(mock_dask.target > 0, 1).head(5)
Out[6]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi @MRocklin thanks for your response. Have edited my question for better understanding, it seems that my code line is converting all 0´s to 1´s. Instead of the values that are 1 or greater than 1 to 1, which is the desired output.