# Subtract increasing values from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Name  a   
b     4   
c     4    
d     4
```

I want to subtract a number from each row in column a, that number is given by an arithmetic sequence (x=x+1) and starts from 1, hence the result will be the below.

```
Name  a   
b     3   
c     2    
d     1
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658240/getting-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-pandas-apply-function

Comment: this has nothing to do with the index, not all data frames have the default index @Maximilian Peters

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
df['a'] = df['a'].sub(np.arange(1, len(df) + 1))
#df['a'] = df['a'] - np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
```

or if default index:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].sub(df.index + 1)
```

**Output**

```
  Name  a
0    b  3
1    c  2
2    d  1
```

we could also do:

```
df['a'] -= df.index + 1
df['a'] -= np.arange(1, len(df)+1)
```