# Get index of row within a sub-DataFrame with pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

This question is related to but different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658240/getting-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-pandas-apply-function), which wonders how to access the row index from within apply. That can be done with `row.name`. However, in my case I am applying a function to `query`'d dataframe, and the row's `name` are just their index in the *original* df. I need them to be zero-based for the queried DataFrame.

```py
import pandas as pd


def print_name(r):
    print(r.name)

data = {"seg": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], "text": ["i", "like", "you", "do", "you", "see"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
sub = df.query("seg==2")
sub.apply(print_name, axis=1)
# 3
# 4
# 5
# Expected 0, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want default index, because filtered rows has original index, there is no change:

```
sub = df.query("seg==2").reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print (df.query("seg==2"))
   seg text
3    2   do
4    2  you
5    2  see

print (df.query("seg==2").reset_index(drop=True))
   seg text
0    2   do
1    2  you
2    2  see
```

Comment: Exactly. Was just going to answer my own question. I thought that dropping the index for the queried DataFrame would also reset it in the original DataFrame, but that is not the case - which is good. So this answers my question.