# getting the column of a row in a pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

### Question

Hi peeps, this question is closely related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658240/getting-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-pandas-apply-function). Instead of getting the `name` of the Series, now I'd like to get the `index` of each particular series. I've tried using the `x.index` but it returns a list of indices instead of the `index` of that particular cell.

```
In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'X': [1,2,3,4,5],
    ...:     'Y': [3,4,5,6,7],
    ...:     'Z': [5,6,7,8,9]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   X  Y  Z
a  1  3  5
b  2  4  6
c  3  5  7
d  4  6  8
e  5  7  9

In [15]: df.apply(lambda x: (x.name, x.index), axis=1)
Out[15]: 
a    (a, [X, Y, Z])
b    (b, [X, Y, Z])
c    (c, [X, Y, Z])
d    (d, [X, Y, Z])
e    (e, [X, Y, Z])
dtype: object
```

### Desired output

I'd like to achieve as the following format. However, I'm not sure how to access the `index` of that particular row. If I use `x.index`, it returns the list of values of the indices.

As you can see in the example, I just want to get the value of each cell to be `(index, column), value`

```
   X           Y          Z
a  (a, X), 1  (a, Y), 3  (a, Z), 5
b  (b, X), 2  (b, Y), 4  (b, Z), 6
c  (c, X), 3  (c, Y), 5  (c, Z), 7
d  (d, X), 4  (d, Y), 6  (d, Z), 8
e  (e, X), 5  (e, Y), 7  (e, Z), 9
```

### Trials

I've tried the following but it won't work since the `index` is hardcoded. I've also checked the  [index docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/indexing.html) but couldn't find any attributes that suits this needs.

```
In [35]: df.apply(lambda x: (x.name, x.index[0]), axis=1)
Out[35]: 
a    (a, X)
b    (b, X)
c    (c, X)
d    (d, X)
e    (e, X)
dtype: object

In [36]: df.apply(lambda x: (x.name, x.index[1]), axis=1)
Out[36]: 
a    (a, Y)
b    (b, Y)
c    (c, Y)
d    (d, Y)
e    (e, Y)
dtype: object

In [37]:
```

I'm thinking that it might be possible to iterate through each column and reassigns the values in it. However, is there a way to do this with `apply()`? Thanks!

Comment: I am a bit confused by your desired output. Why is the first element of each tuple `a`? Shouldn't the first element of each tuple match the index in the same row?

Comment: Ah yes, you are right @Derek, fixed in the revision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly modify the `row` Series and return the modified `row` Series.

```py
def convert(row):
    for col in row.index:
        row[col] = f'({row.name}, {col}), {row[col]}'
    return row

df = df.apply(convert, axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

           X          Y          Z
a  (a, X), 1  (a, Y), 3  (a, Z), 5
b  (b, X), 2  (b, Y), 4  (b, Z), 6
c  (c, X), 3  (c, Y), 5  (c, Z), 7
d  (d, X), 4  (d, Y), 6  (d, Z), 8
e  (e, X), 5  (e, Y), 7  (e, Z), 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm curious, since there is a loop going on on each column/row, how would this affect the time/space complexity of the algorithm? I'd ask this because I'd be dealing with a data that is not too small and relatively big and performance would be a slight concern.

Comment: @TotoLele Say your pandas have `m` rows  and `n` columns. The time complexity would be `O(m*n)`.