# Incrementing 1 to all strings in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column filled with the same string on all rows (E.g 'asd12_01').
Is it possible to increment 1 to all rows?
here is what it would look like at the end:

```
1 'asd12_01'
2 'asd12_02'
3 'asd12_03'
```

I tried creating a simple function but it did not work. I tried cumcount too, but also didnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting the index of a row in a pandas apply function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658240/getting-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-pandas-apply-function)

Comment: Is that a well-known string or do you need to parse the existing string somehow? How would a string that goes over 100 look?

Comment: Can you have strings other than `asd12_xx`?

Answer (score 3):

Using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['new'] = (df['col']
             .str.extract(r'^(.*?)\d*$', expand=False)
             .add(df.groupby('col').cumcount()
                    .add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2))
             )
```

Output:

```
        col       new
0  asd12_01  asd12_01
1  asd12_01  asd12_02
2  asd12_01  asd12_03
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['asd12_01'] * 5})
def increment_string(s, i):
    prefix, num = s.rsplit('_', 1)
    return f"{prefix}_{int(num) + i:02d}"
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda x: increment_string(x['col1'], x.name), axis=1)
print(df)
```

The above code creates a sample `dataframe` with a column col1 filled with the same string 'asd12_01' on all rows. It then defines a function increment_string that takes in a string s and an integer i, and returns a new string where the number after the last underscore is incremented by i. The function is then applied to each row of the `dataframe` using the apply method, with x.name representing the row index. The resulting `dataframe` will have the col1 column incremented by 1 for each row, as shown below:

```
       col1
0  asd12_01
1  asd12_02
2  asd12_03
3  asd12_04
4  asd12_05
```