# How to select column names in python pandas by dataframe values?

Tags: python, select, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(10, 5) > 1, index=range(1, 11), columns=list('ABCDE'))

        A      B      C      D      E
1   False  False  False  False  False
2   False  False  False  False  False
3    True   True  False   True  False
4   False  False   True   True  False
5   False  False  False  False  False
6   False  False  False  False  False
7   False  False  False  False  False
8   False  False  False  False  False
9   False  False  False  False  False
10  False   True  False   True  False
```

For each row I would like to get the column name that is the last one in that row containing True.
If there isn't any, return any resonable value.
How can I do that?

Comment: you need to re-examine your example code. `list('ABCDE')` ??

Comment: @JDLong what's wrong with that? Calling `list()` on a string returns each character in the string individually, which is what is desired here. It's easier than writing `columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']`.

Comment: doesnt on my box `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: sorry about that... i had a list named list in my workspace. Oops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one liner:

```
>>> value = np.nan
>>> df.reindex_axis(df.columns[::-1], axis=1)\  # flip vertically
      .idxmax(axis=1)\                          # find last(now first) True value 
      .reset_index()\                           # get index for the next step
      .apply(lambda x: value if (x[0]==df.columns[-1] and not df.ix[x['index'], x[0]]) 
                         else x[0], axis=1)     # =value if col=="E" and value==False
Out [1]:
0    NaN
1    NaN
2      D
3      D
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9      D
```

**Explanation:**

`idxmax` returns the index of the max value in a row, if there is more than one max it returns the first one. We want the last one so we flip the dataframe vertically.

Finally we must replace the obtained Series with `value` if `col=="E"` and `value==False`. You can't apply a condition on the index of a Series, thats why you need the `reset_index` first.

This last step could be more elegantly done with `df.replace({'E': {False: value})`, which replaces `False` in column 'E' with `value`, but somehow it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Very nice. At bit complicated to understand but works.

Comment: Yep, pandas should have an easier way to do such things, like applying a condition on an index, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316211/access-index-in-pandas-series-apply).

Answer (score 0):

set up the example data first:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame( (randn(10, 5) > 1) , index=range(1, 11), columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
df
```

looks like:

```
        A      B      C      D      E
1    True  False  False  False  False
2   False   True  False  False  False
3    True  False  False  False   True
4   False  False  False  False  False
5   False   True  False  False  False
6   False  False  False  False  False
7   False  False  False  False  False
8   False  False  False   True  False
9   False  False  False   True  False
10  False  False   True  False  False
```

it sounds like what you want to do is get the index # for each true value and then select the max index #. On a single column that might look like the following:

```
df['A'][df['A']].index.max()
```

which returns 3. To do this for all the columns, the easiest is to iterate through each column and shove the result in a list:

```
mylist = []
for col in df.columns:
    myval = df[col][df[col]].index.max()
    mylist.append(myval)

mylist
```

that returns:

```
[3, 5, 10, 9, 3]
```

the loop logic above returns nan if there is no True value in the column.

Comment: I wanted the same thing but per row and not column. Meaning    
  `['A', 'B', 'E', NaN, 'B', NaN, 'Nan', 'D', 'D', 'C']`

Comment: Woops... I see that now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, with a transpose on the original frame and the result this actually works