# Conditional on pandas DataFrame's

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements

Let `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` are `pandas.DataFrame`'s having the same structure but different numerical values. I want to perform:

```
res=if df1>1.0: (df2-df3)/(df1-1) else df3
```

`res` should have the same structure as `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` have.

`numpy.where()` generates result as a flat array.

**Edit 1:**

`res` should have the same indices as `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` have.

For example, I can access `df2` as `df2["instanceA"]["parameter1"]["paramter2"]`. I want to access the new calculated DataFrame/Series `res` as `res["instanceA"]["parameter1"]["paramter2"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `numpy.where` should work fine there.  Output here is 4x2 (same as df1, df2, df3).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(4,2), columns=list('xy') )
df2 = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(4,2), columns=list('xy') )
df3 = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(4,2), columns=list('xy') )

res = df3.copy()
res[:] = np.where( df1 > 1, (df2-df3)/(df1-1), df3 )

          x         y
0 -0.671787 -0.445276
1 -0.609351 -0.881987
2  0.324390  1.222632
3 -0.138606  0.955993
```

Note that this should work on both series and dataframes.  The `[:]` is slicing syntax that preserves the index and columns.  Without that `res` will come out as an array rather than series or dataframe.

Alternatively, for a series you could write as @Kadir does in his answer:

```
res = pd.Series(np.where( df1>1, (df2-df3)/(df1-1), df3 ), index=df1.index)
```

Or similarly for a dataframe you could write:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(np.where( df1>1, (df2-df3)/(df1-1), df3 ), index=df1.index,
                                                              columns=df1.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Integrating the idea in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316211/access-index-in-pandas-series-apply) into JohnE's answer, I have come up with this solution:

```
res = pd.Series(np.where( df1 > 1, (df2-df3)/(df1-1), df3 ), index=df1.index)
```

A better answer using DataFrames will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Say df is your initial dataframe and res is the new column.  Use a combination of setting values and boolean indexing.

Set res to be a copy of df3:

```
 df['res'] = df['df3']
```

Then adjust values for your condition.

```
df[df['df1']>1.0]['res'] = (df['df2'] - df['df3'])/(df['df1']-1)
```

Comment: I believe df1/df2/df3 should be dataframes, not columns.