# Get pandas series index in data

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I want to format a series of strings so the index is in the string somewhere.  Example series:

```
ser = pd.Series(['CT', 'NY', 'MT'], index=['Jessica', 'Eric', 'Toby'])
ser
Jessica    CT
Eric       NY
Toby       MT
dtype: object
```

The desired output:

```
Jessica    Jessica: CT
Eric          Eric: NY
Toby          Toby: MT
dtype: object
```

I've tried variants of this:

```
ser.apply(lambda x: "{}: {}".format(x.index, x))
```

but it doesn't work because `x.index` refers to the index method of `str`, not the series being iterated over.

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access index in pandas.Series.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316211/access-index-in-pandas-series-apply)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
[**`pd.Index.to_series`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html)

```
ser.index.to_series() + ': ' + ser

Jessica    Jessica: CT
Eric          Eric: NY
Toby          Toby: MT
dtype: object
```

---

**Option 2** My favorite!
[**`pd.Series.radd`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.radd.html)

```
ser.radd(ser.index + ': ')

Jessica    Jessica: CT
Eric          Eric: NY
Toby          Toby: MT
dtype: object
```

---

**Option 3**

```
pd.Series(map(': '.join, zip(ser.index, ser)), ser.index)

Jessica    Jessica: CT
Eric          Eric: NY
Toby          Toby: MT
dtype: object
```