# Filter Pandas Series using both index and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a clean way to filter Pandas Series using a custom function that takes as input both index and value?

Here is a piece of code that achieves what I want to do:

```
series = pd.Series({"id5":88, "id3":40})
def custom(k,v):
    if k=="id5":
        return v>20
    else:
        return v>50

filtered_indexes = []
filtered_values = []
for k,v in series.iteritems():
    if custom(k,v):
        filtered_indexes.append(k)
        filtered_values.append(v)
filtered_series = pd.Series(data=filtered_values, index=filtered_indexes)
```

My question is: can the same be achieved cleaner and/or more efficiently with syntax like

```
series.filter(lambda x: custom(x.index, x.value))
```

Comment: Ca you add data sample?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) [have no accesses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18316830) to index and [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) is not implemented for `Series`.

It is possible, but need create `DataFrame`:

```
s = series[series.to_frame().apply(lambda x: custom(x.name, x), axis=1).squeeze()]
print (s)
id5    88
dtype: int64
```

Or use `groupby` with [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
s = series.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: custom(x.name, x)[0])
print (s)
id5    88
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorise your logic as below. This avoids inefficient `lambda` loops and may also make your code cleaner.

```
res = series[((series.index == 'id5') & (series > 20)) |
             ((series.index != 'id5') & (series > 50))]
```

Result:

```
id5    88
dtype: int64
```

For readability, you may wish to separate the Boolean criteria:

```
c1 = ((series.index == 'id5') & (series > 20))
c2 = ((series.index != 'id5') & (series > 50))

res = series[c1 | c2]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is missing the custom function and the sample I provided is just a "toy example". The actual function is more complicated and can't be expressed this way.

Comment: So link `c1 = f(series.index, series)` where `f` is your custom function? Just make sure `f` returns an array. The general point is the same, and this solution is adaptable to any function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Especially wrt to "make sure `f` returns an array". That sounds like `f` would simply contain all the ugly code I was trying to get rid off in the first place. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes. It's good practice to have each function do something different.  You haven't explained what `f(index, series)` involves, so I can't comment further. But if it's a numeric computation it's most likely you can optimize via `numpy` / `numba` / other tools. Of course, you can always take @jezrael's approach and convert your series to a dataframe..